# get the clicked imageview swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to know which imageview was clicked by the user I am using the following code, but it is not calling the `leftTapView` and `rightTapView` functions

```
class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var leftTeamImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var rightTeamImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var rightTeamNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var leftTeamNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var leftTeamScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var rightTeamScoreLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet var leftView : UIView!
    @IBOutlet var rightView : UIView!

    let lettTapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    let rightTapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    ScoreLabel.text = leftTeamScore
        rightTeamNameLabel.text = rightTeamName.uppercaseString
        rightTeamScoreLabel.text = rightTeamScore
    }
    func load(#leftTeamName: String, rightTeamName: String, leftTeamScore: Int, rightTeamScore: Int) {

        leftTeamNameLabel.text = leftTeamName.uppercaseString
        leftTeamScoreLabel.text = String(leftTeamScore)
        rightTeamNameLabel.text = rightTeamName.uppercaseString
        rightTeamScoreLabel.text = String(rightTeamScore)



lettTapRec.addTarget(self, action: "leftTapView")
        leftView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        leftView.addGestureRecognizer(lettTapRec)
        //
        rightTapRec.addTarget(self, action: "rightTapView")
        rightView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        rightView.addGestureRecognizer(rightTapRec)
    }



    func leftTapView(sender: AnyObject){
        println("left")
    }
    func rightTapView(sender: AnyObject){
        println("left")
    }
}

protocol ImageTappedProtocols {
    func leftImageTapped(imageView : UIImage)
    func rightImageTapped(imageView: UIImage)
}
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!

    var items: [(String, String)] = [
        ("My", "swift 1.jpeg"),
        ("Name", "swift 2.jpeg"),
        ("is", "swift 3.jpeg"),
        ("Atif", "swift 4.jpeg"),
        ("Farrukh", "swift 5.jpeg")
    ]
    var team1 :[String] = []
    var team2 :[String] = []
    var id : [String] = []
    var team1_bets : [Int] = []
    var team2_bets : [Int] = []
    var end_date : [String] = []

    var list = Dictionary<String, String>()
    var count : Int = 0

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:CustomTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell") as CustomTableViewCell

        // this is how you extract values from a tuple
        var (title, image) = items[indexPath.row]
        var teama: String = team1[indexPath.row]
        var teamb: String = team2[indexPath.row]
        var teamAScore : Int  = team1_bets[indexPath.row]
        var teamBScore : Int  = team2_bets[indexPath.row]

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 123, green: 225, blue: 38, alpha: 0.2)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView : UITableView, didSelectedRowAtIndexPath indexPath : NSIndexPath){
        //tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

        println(currentCell.textLabel.text)
    }
    func tableView(tableView : UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath : NSIndexPath){
        //tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!

        println(currentCell.contentView)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let urlAsString = "http://codespikestudios.com/betting_app/bet/get_events/1"
        //let urlAsString = "http://api.topcoder.com/v2/challenges?pageSize=2"
        let url: NSURL  = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
        let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        //2
        let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            var err: NSError?

            // 3
            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSArray
            if (err != nil) {
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }

            // 4
            println(jsonResult)
            println(jsonResult.count)
            println(jsonResult[1].valueForKey("cat_name") as String)

            var dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()

            self.count = jsonResult.count
            for var i = 0; i < self.count; i++ {


                self.team1 = jsonResult.valueForKey("team1") as Array
                self.team2 = jsonResult.valueForKey("team2") as Array
                self.team1_bets = jsonResult.valueForKey("team1_bets") as Array
                self.team2_bets = jsonResult.valueForKey("team2_bets") as Array

            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            //let jsonDate: String! = jsonResult["date"] as NSString
            //let jsonTime: String! = jsonResult["time"] as NSString

            //println(jsonTime)
        })
        // 5
        jsonQuery.resume()


        var nib = UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

this is all I get

```
You selected cell #3!
<UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7f871b687350; frame = (0 0; 580 136.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f871b68c180>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f871b687420>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view with an `alpha` of 0.0 won't receive touch events.

From the [Event Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html) guide:

> "Note that a view also does not receive touch events if it’s hidden or transparent."

From the [Creating Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html) documentation:

> "A hidden view does not receive touch events from the system."

Answer (score 1):

You will want to add a target when you initialize your gesture recognizers. That would look like, for instance:

```
let leftTapRect = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "leftTapView:")
```

In addition, you will need to add a sender argument to your event handlers leftTapView and rightTapView:

```
func leftTapView(sender: AnyObject) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: edited my question, kindly look at it please. still same response.

Comment: I believe there are complications related to sending events to children of a table view cell like your tap recognizer. I would suggest searching in that direction. Good luck.

Comment: thank you solved my problem, Actually i had set my view's alpha to `0`, when I set it to `1` and made the set the background as `Clear Colour` it started working, can you please tell why making alpha 0 doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

solved my problem, Actually i had set my view's alpha to 0, when I set it to 1 and made the set the background as `Clear Colour` it started working. Rest the working perfectly. If someone can explain the reason of why setting alpha doesnt trigger the tap gesture I will gladly accept hi/her answer as accepted.